# How to remove bullets from ul?

Tags: css, list, bullet

I've read multiple topics with this same question and tried following all instructions but I can't seem to remove the bullets from the following `<ul> <li>` segment.

```
<div id="mobile-contact-bar-outer">
<ul>
<li><a data-rel="external" href="tel:+18885551212"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa-fw fas fa-phone"></i>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Phone Number for calling</span></span></a></li>
<li><a data-rel="external" href="mailto:name@email.com"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa-fw far fa-envelope"></i><span class="screen-reader-text">Email Address</span></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I've added both:

```
div#mobile-contact-bar-outer {
    list-style-type: none!important;
}

div#mobile-contact-bar {
    list-style-type: none!important;
}
```

Neither have any effect.  What am I missing?  No caching on site.

Answer (score 1):

Add `list-style: none` to the UL tag. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) reference

```
ul {
    list-style: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does it, you have to edit the ul tag directly as list-style-type isn't valid on divs

```css
div#mobile-contact-bar-outer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div#mobile-contact-bar ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-contact-bar-outer">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-rel="external" href="tel:+18885551212"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa-fw fas fa-phone"></i>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Phone Number for calling</span></span></a></li>
    <li><a data-rel="external" href="mailto:name@email.com"><span class="fa-stack fa-3x"><i class="fa-fw far fa-envelope"></i><span class="screen-reader-text">Email Address</span></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Added 'div#mobile-contact-bar-outer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

div#mobile-contact-bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}' but no change.  Still have bullets!

Comment: Do you have any other styles affecting the ul tags? If you click "Run code snippet" you can see no bullets show for your code with just these snippets, that means something else must be affect it

Comment: There could be, but adding !important should eliminate that possibility right?  There are no other calls in the native tags for any styles.  Since this is called only on mobile, perhaps I should be adding '@media screen'?

Comment: Yeah !important should unless you also use important elsewhere that affects it. If you inspect the element in dev-tools what styles show on the ul tag? Media queries wont override the !important tag, they just get added to the cascade on applicable devices/sizes

Comment: This is all that's applied to ul.      border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

Answer (score 0):

you can either add a class to your  element like

```
<ul class="newclass">
```

and add you list-style-type: none to that element like

```
ul.newclass{
list-style-type: none
}
```

this new class will allow more control to this individual ul element

or add the class to your div

```
div#mobile-contact-bar-outer ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

no need for the important tag now.